# Get "this" within the parent class

Tags: javascript, oop

My problem is I can't access the proper *this* object in my parent class.

**Parent class :**

```
ViewController.prototype.display = function() {
    console.log(this); // Log a Window object
};
```

**Child class :**

```
ParentMissionsViewController.prototype = Object.create(ViewController.prototype);
ParentMissionsViewController.prototype.constructor = ParentMissionsViewController;
ParentMissionsViewController.prototype.parent = ViewController.prototype;

ParentMissionsViewController.prototype.display = function() {
    // Other stuff here
    this.parent.display.call();
};
```

I don't get why this isn't my current object, if someone can explain me ?

Comment: Inside a function, the value of `this` depends on how the function is called. [It is best explained on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: You've already set the prototype of the class to use `ViewController.prototype`, so it seems like you should be calling `this.display()`.

Comment: @zzzzBov it's inheritance, if I call `this.display()` it calls the same function

Comment: @AncAinu, somehow I completely missed that it was being called in the new `display` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call

```
this.parent.display();
```

then it looks like:

```
var that = this.parent;
that.display();
```

which you, as I suppose, wanted to avert. Using `call` is the good way, but you need to provide the value for `this`:

```
this.parent.display.call(this /* , arg, arg... */);
```

See [the signature of `call` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.parent.display();
```

When you use call to invoke a method, you need to specify custom this value as first argument. What this value are you getting in current code? I am guessing undefined?